# infinispan error when interface public modified wildfly 9

Tags: deployment, infinispan, wildfly-9

i have a domain with only one node when i configure the interface public in host.xml with the server IP it cause this error:

2018-06-14 12:56:42,804 WARNING [org.jgroups.protocols.UDP] (INT-1,ee,master:server-one) JGRP000012: discarded message from different cluster hq-cluster (our cluster is ee). Sender was master:server-one (received 97 identical messages from master:server-one in the last 60233 ms)

2018-06-14 12:56:42,866 WARNING [org.jgroups.protocols.UDP] (INT-2,ee,master:server-one) JGRP000012: discarded message from different cluster hq-cluster (our cluster is ee). Sender was master:server-one (received 87 identical messages from master:server-one in the last 60280 ms)

2018-06-14 12:56:45,378 WARNING [org.jgroups.protocols.UDP] (INT-1,hq-cluster,master:server-one) JGRP000012: discarded message from different cluster ee (our cluster is hq-cluster). Sender was master:server-one (received 41 identical messages from master:server-one in the last 61963 ms)

2018-06-14 12:56:45,441 WARNING [org.jgroups.protocols.UDP] (INT-2,hq-cluster,master:server-one) JGRP000012: discarded message from different cluster ee (our cluster is hq-cluster). Sender was master:server-one (received 27 identical messages from master:server-one in the last 60198 ms)

2018-06-14 12:56:58,894 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.infinispan.ejb.dist: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.infinispan.ejb.dist: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManagerImpl.start() throws java.lang.Exception on object of type StateTransferManagerImpl

at org.wildfly.clustering.service.AsynchronousServiceBuilder$1.run(AsynchronousServiceBuilder.java:107)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)

Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManagerImpl.start() throws java.lang.Exception on object of type StateTransferManagerImpl

at org.infinispan.commons.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeAccessibly(ReflectionUtil.java:171)

at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry$PrioritizedMethod.invoke(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:869)

at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.invokeStartMethods(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:638)

at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.internalStart(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:627)

at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.start(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:530)

at org.infinispan.factories.ComponentRegistry.start(ComponentRegistry.java:218)

at org.infinispan.cache.impl.CacheImpl.start(CacheImpl.java:850)

at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.wireAndStartCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:599)

at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.createCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:554)

at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.getCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:424)

at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.getCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:438)

at org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan.DefaultCacheContainer.getCache(DefaultCacheContainer.java:118)

at org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan.DefaultCacheContainer.getCache(DefaultCacheContainer.java:109)

at org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.spi.service.CacheBuilder.start(CacheBuilder.java:79)

at org.wildfly.clustering.service.AsynchronousServiceBuilder$1.run(AsynchronousServiceBuilder.java:102)

... 4 more

Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Bad response received from coordinator: CacheNotFoundResponse

at org.infinispan.topology.LocalTopologyManagerImpl.executeOnCoordinator(LocalTopologyManagerImpl.java:525)

at org.infinispan.topology.LocalTopologyManagerImpl.join(LocalTopologyManagerImpl.java:117)

at org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManagerImpl.start(StateTransferManagerImpl.java:110)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

at org.infinispan.commons.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeAccessibly(ReflectionUtil.java:168)

... 18 more

2018-06-14 12:56:58,894 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([

```
("subsystem" => "infinispan"),

("cache-container" => "ejb"),

("distributed-cache" => "dist")
```

]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.infinispan.ejb.dist" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.infinispan.ejb.dist: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManagerImpl.start() throws java.lang.Exception on object of type StateTransferManagerImpl

```
Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManagerImpl.start() throws java.lang.Exception on object of type StateTransferManagerImpl

Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Bad response received from coordinator: CacheNotFoundResponse"}
```

If i let 127.0.0.1 it work like a charm but server not accessible from other IPs.

configuration:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:3.0">

            <cache-container name="server" default-cache="default" module="org.wildfly.clustering.server" aliases="singleton cluster">

                <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>

                <replicated-cache name="default" mode="SYNC">

                    <transaction mode="BATCH"/>

                </replicated-cache>

            </cache-container>

            <cache-container name="web" default-cache="dist" module="org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan">

                <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>

                <distributed-cache name="dist" mode="ASYNC" owners="2" l1-lifespan="0">

                    <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>

                    <transaction mode="BATCH"/>

                    <file-store/>

                </distributed-cache>

            </cache-container>

            <cache-container name="ejb" default-cache="dist" module="org.wildfly.clustering.ejb.infinispan" aliases="sfsb">

                <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>

                <distributed-cache name="dist" mode="ASYNC" owners="2" l1-lifespan="0">

                    <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>

                    <transaction mode="BATCH"/>

                    <file-store/>

                </distributed-cache>

            </cache-container>

            <cache-container name="hibernate" default-cache="local-query" module="org.hibernate.infinispan">

                <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>

                <local-cache name="local-query">

                    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>

                    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>

                </local-cache>

                <invalidation-cache name="entity" mode="SYNC">

                    <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>

                    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>

                    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>

                </invalidation-cache>

                <replicated-cache name="timestamps" mode="ASYNC"/>

            </cache-container>

        </subsystem>

        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:iiop-openjdk:1.0">

            <orb socket-binding="iiop" ssl-socket-binding="iiop-ssl"/>

            <initializers security="identity" transactions="spec"/>

        </subsystem>

        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jaxrs:1.0"/>

        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jca:3.0">

            <archive-validation enabled="true" fail-on-error="true" fail-on-warn="false"/>

            <bean-validation enabled="true"/>

            <default-workmanager>

                <short-running-threads>

                    <core-threads count="50"/>

                    <queue-length count="50"/>

                    <max-threads count="50"/>

                    <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>

                </short-running-threads>

                <long-running-threads>

                    <core-threads count="50"/>

                    <queue-length count="50"/>

                    <max-threads count="50"/>

                    <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>

                </long-running-threads>

            </default-workmanager>

            <cached-connection-manager/>

        </subsystem>

        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jdr:1.0"/>

        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jgroups:3.0">

            <channels default="ee">

                <channel name="ee"/>

            </channels>

            <stacks default="udp">

                <stack name="udp">

                    <transport type="UDP" socket-binding="jgroups-udp"/>

                    <protocol type="PING"/>

                    <protocol type="MERGE3"/>

                    <protocol type="FD_SOCK" socket-binding="jgroups-udp-fd"/>

                    <protocol type="FD_ALL"/>

                    <protocol type="VERIFY_SUSPECT"/>

                    <protocol type="pbcast.NAKACK2"/>

                    <protocol type="UNICAST3"/>

                    <protocol type="pbcast.STABLE"/>

                    <protocol type="pbcast.GMS"/>

                    <protocol type="UFC"/>

                    <protocol type="MFC"/>

                    <protocol type="FRAG2"/>

                    <protocol type="RSVP"/>

                </stack>

                <stack name="tcp">

                    <transport type="TCP" socket-binding="jgroups-tcp"/>

                    <protocol type="MPING" socket-binding="jgroups-mping"/>

                    <protocol type="MERGE3"/>

                    <protocol type="FD_SOCK" socket-binding="jgroups-tcp-fd"/>

                    <protocol type="FD"/>

                    <protocol type="VERIFY_SUSPECT"/>

                    <protocol type="pbcast.NAKACK2"/>

                    <protocol type="UNICAST3"/>

                    <protocol type="pbcast.STABLE"/>

                    <protocol type="pbcast.GMS"/>

                    <protocol type="MFC"/>

                    <protocol type="FRAG2"/>

                    <protocol type="RSVP"/>

                </stack>

            </stacks>

        </subsystem>
```

```
    <socket-binding-group name="full-ha-sockets" default-interface="public">

        <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/>

        <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:80}"/>

        <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>

        <socket-binding name="iiop" interface="unsecure" port="3528"/>

        <socket-binding name="iiop-ssl" interface="unsecure" port="3529"/>

        <socket-binding name="jgroups-mping" port="0" multicast-address="${jboss.default.multicast.address:230.0.0.4}" multicast-port="45700"/>

        <socket-binding name="jgroups-tcp" port="7600"/>

        <socket-binding name="jgroups-tcp-fd" port="57600"/>

        <socket-binding name="jgroups-udp" port="55200" multicast-address="${jboss.default.multicast.address:230.0.0.4}" multicast-port="45688"/>

        <socket-binding name="jgroups-udp-fd" port="54200"/>

        <socket-binding name="modcluster" port="0" multicast-address="224.0.1.105" multicast-port="23364"/>

        <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>

        <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>

        <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">

            <remote-destination host="10.102.225.166" port="25"/>

        </outbound-socket-binding>

        <outbound-socket-binding name="server-one">

            <remote-destination host="172.31.20.102" port="80"/>

        </outbound-socket-binding>

    </socket-binding-group>

</socket-binding-groups>
```

Have you an idea ?

Comment: You seem to have two clusters running in same network. Make sure they're using different multicast addresses by starting one of them with `-Djboss.default.multicast.address=x.x.x.x`. Default is `234.99.54.14`

Comment: thank you !the customer assume us we have only one wildfly on the network

Answer (score 1):

based on Galder advice, i switched to TCP stack instead UDP and it works fine. Maybe something on the network causes issue.